Homotopy groups of the space of diffeomorphisms
Let $M$ be a smooth, closed, and connected manifold of dimension $n \geq 5$. Let $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ denote the space of diffeomorphisms of $M$ with the $C^\infty$-topology.
Is there a general method for computing the homotopy groups $\pi_k(\operatorname{Diff}(M))$ for all $k \geq 0$? More specifically:
Does there exist an integer $s(M)$ such that the homotopy groups $\pi_k(\operatorname{Diff}(M))$ stabilize for $k \geq s(M)$, i.e., $\pi_k(\operatorname{Diff}(M)) \cong \pi_{k+1}(\operatorname{Diff}(M))$ for all $k \geq s(M)$? If so, can we give an explicit formula for $s(M)$ in terms of the topology of $M$?

There is no stability of the sort you are looking for.  The reason is fairly simple-minded.  For example, the orthogonal groups do not have the homotopic stability you are looking for, and diffeomorphism groups sometimes fiber over orthogonal groups, i.e. $Diff(S^n) \simeq O_{n+1} \times Diff(D^n)$.
Is there a general method of computation?  Not really.  But in broad outlines there is what Hatcher outlined in his Higher Simple Homotopy Theory paper.  That paper has some flaws but most of them have been patched.  At present it is quite difficult to derive concrete statements about any homotopy groups of diffeomorphism groups of manifolds in dimension $n \geq 4$, but there are a few families of techniques that allow people to deduce properties of the rational homotopy type, or information about $2$-torsion, etc.
There is a different sort of stability called pseudoisotopy stability but  the dimension of the homotopy groups remains constant, and it's the underlying manifold that is stabilized.  This is The Journal K-theory, vol. 1 (Kiyoshi Igusa).
There is another sort of stability that has been getting attention recently, where you take the connect sum of your manifold $M$ with a standard manifold; often it is a product of spheres or a complex projective space.  There is a significant literature on this type of stability, and strong results even in dimension $4$.  For example, look up papers of Giansiracusa.
Not sure if that answers your question, but it's too much for a comment.

Ryan, it was not Igusa's PhD thesis (the latter which was on correcting the Hatcher-Wagoner exact sequence). The stability theorem came a bit later.

Thanks John, I thought the stability result was a part of his thesis. . . but I think I was just confused by the section titles.  I haven't read his thesis closely.
